# What can i do to not enter in infinite loop when i add the data10? the problem is that it change the state once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What can i do to not enter in infinite loop when i add the data10? the problem is that it change the state once and not on every task added.

so the data is from a query (apollo client). i m setting the setData with data. The thing is that when i wanna add a task, i want setData10 to add a new task at the end of the array and if i put data10 in the dependency array in useEffect hook,  it enters in infinite loop and if i m not putting it, it change it only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // if (cacheStore) {
      getDog();
    }

    if (data) {
      setData10(data);
    }

    if (tasks) {
      setData10((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        user: {
          ...prev.user,
          tasks: [
            ...prev.user.tasks,
            { name: "eduard", completed: false, id: "21312312" }
          ]
        }
      }));
    }

    // if (logout) {
      setCacheStore(null);
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }

    // if (!logout) {
      setCacheStore(token?.login.token);
      localStorage.setItem("token", token?.login.token);
    }
  }, [
    loading1,
    tasks,
    data5,
    setData10,
    getDog,
    token,
    data,
    cacheStore,
    logout
  ])
```

Comment: Can you code a full snippet?

Comment: Hello! To let people help you, you should:
- reduce your code to the minimum needed to serve your question, by removing, generalizing or commenting lines that are specific to your code and not necessary to understand the issue;
- add the expected behavior (what you want your code to do), and the actual one (what it does instead) with words everybody can understand (for example, what do "state", "add data10", ... mean?

Comment: i just edited, thanks for letting me know. hope you ll understand